# Iterating data from Joined Tables using Jinja2 Nested For Loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

For the purpose of this example consider the following `table` which has a `parent` row iterating a list of "orders" and each "order" has several `child` rows iterating a list of "items" for a given "order".

The list of "orders" and "items" are contained in separate `tables` joined together when we render our template with a `query`:

```
def order_items_template():
    return render_template('order_items_template.html', 
      order_items_query = db.session.query(orders)
      .join(items, orders.id == items.order_id)
      .all())
```

Note below that we are also using a `bootstrap collapsible accordion` to display parent/child rows.

```
{% for order in orders %} 

    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{ order.number }}" class="clickable">
        <td>{{ order.number }}</td>        
    </tr>

        {% for item in order %}
            <tr class="no-border collapse" id="{{ order.number }}">
                <td>{{ item.name }}</td>                                          
            </tr>
        {% endfor %} 

{% endfor %}
```

Additionally we are joining the two tables with an `sqlalchemy ForeignKey relationship`:

```
class items (db.Model):
   id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key = True)
   item = db.Column(db.String(100)) 
   order_id = db.Column(db.Integer)

class orders (db.Model):
   id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key = True)
   orders = db.Column(db.String(100)) 
   item_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('items.order_id'), nullable=False)
   item_relashionship = relationship("items")
```

Although the `parent` rows are displayed the data in the `rows` is not. Does anyone see where the problem lies?

edit: by changing the "child" `jinja2 loop` from `{{ % for item in order % }}` to `{{ % for item in order.items % }}` as suggested below no data is returned and the `bootstrap accordion` is "broken" and no longer collapses.

For testing purposes, adding `{{ order.item_relashionship.name }}` placeholder to the "parent loop" returns the name of an `item` matching an `order_id` which is obviously wrong.

What we want is the corresponding list of `items` for each `order`. This must have something to do with the relationship between the two tables but I can't figure out what is missing.

Answer (score 1):

When you query the result and passing the data to html try adding a temporary column with the order number details so that you can iterate thru order and show it in the screen. I had faced a similar requirement before and achieved it by below method.

```
queryset1= table1.objects.all().annotate(order=Value('value1', CharField()))
queryset2= table2.objects.all().annotate(order=Value('value2', CharField()))
all_items = list(queryset1) + list(queryset2) 
all_items_feed = sorted(all_items, key=lambda obj: obj.type)
return render(request, 'page.html', {'all_items_feed' : all_items_feed})
```

and in the html page iterate thru the all_items_feed by checking the condition as below

```
{% if all_items_feed %}
    {% for items in all_items_feed %}
        {% if items.order == 'value1' %}
        populate the html collapse content for every order here
```

Comment: Makes sense. I'm getting `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'annotate'` from `queryset1` though so need to figure out where that is coming from.

Comment: As far as I understand I'm initialising values as `list` whereas I should be using `instances` but my knowledge is limited as to initiate the latter instead of the former.

Comment: Any chance you can help?

Answer (score 0):

A simple guess, but I'm thinking you need to something along the lines of this:

```
{% for item in order.items %} <-- Note the change in order to order.items
    <tr class="no-border collapse" id="{{ order.number }}">
        <td>{{ item.name}}</td>                                          
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

You need to iterate through the objects `items` for your sub data

Comment: Getting closer to the solution I believe as this issue is definately with the "connection" between `order` and `items` but still doesn't work. I've added an edit to my initial post with more details.